# How to unzip in Flutter, got error "Invalid uncompressed block header"

Tags: flutter, unzip

I'm trying to unzip a password-protected zip file in Flutter. But got an error:

> Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid uncompressed block header

The codes:

```
import 'package:archive/archive_io.dart';
...
extractFileToDisk(path + "/a.zip", path, password: "a_password");
...
```

The complete log:

```
E/flutter (11745): #0      Inflate._parseUncompressedBlock (package:archive/src/zlib/inflate.dart:198:7)
E/flutter (11745): #1      Inflate._parseBlock (package:archive/src/zlib/inflate.dart:116:9)
E/flutter (11745): #2      Inflate._inflate (package:archive/src/zlib/inflate.dart:92:20)
E/flutter (11745): #3      new Inflate.buffer (package:archive/src/zlib/inflate.dart:22:5)
E/flutter (11745): #4      ArchiveFile.decompress (package:archive/src/archive_file.dart:76:28)
E/flutter (11745): #5      ArchiveFile.content (package:archive/src/archive_file.dart:67:7)
E/flutter (11745): #6      extractFileToDisk (package:archive/src/io/extract_archive_to_disk.dart:67:29)
E/flutter (11745): #7      _MyHomePageState.initState.extractFile (package:my_project/main.dart:116:9)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that the `.zip` file is valid and that the password correct?  If you've verified that the file can be unzipped with other tools using the specified password, then the appropriate action to take is to file an issue with the package author.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the file is valid. OK then, I'll report an issue.